# div float and position

Tags: css, html, position

my problem is about positioning a div. i have a div with dynamic height, sometimes it is 600px and sometimes it's 300 and so on, let's call that div, div A. Now i want to put another div inside div A and want to position it always on the bottom right, let's call this div B.

I know one way with positioning div B relative and do stuff with bottom:xy but in this case it isn't working, because my div A changes dynamically it's height.

My question is, is this possible? Do i need Javascript for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using absolute position

```
<div class="d1">
<div class="d2"></div>
</div>​

.d1{
   position:relative; 
   height:350px; width:150px; 
   background-color:grey
  }
.d2{
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:0; right:0;
  background-color:red;
  height:60px; width:80px; 
 }​
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/aMdrr/

You can change the d1 div height to test the effect

Comment: aww so easy and smooth. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible and i just made a simple example for you :

http://jsfiddle.net/ujf9D/

NOTE: I use a js script try to manipulate your dynamic width/height situations.

Comment: You can use position: relative for your parent div ( this will make no visual effect for users), but this will change the behavior it original was.

Comment: after that, set position: absolute for your child div and make it right-bottom. In this way, it will do exactly as what you originally thought.